# Extracting zip file on host by PHP destroys directory structure

Tags: php, directory, zip, php-ziparchive

I have a directory structure like this :

```
members/
  login.php
  register.php
```

I zip them by PHP ZipArchive in my windows machine, but when I upload it to linux host and extract there by PHP it gives me these as two files with no directory :

```
members\login.php
members\register.php
```

I want to have the complete directory structure on the host after unzipping the file.
Note that this unpacking code runs without any problem in my local machine. Is it something about windows and linux or what? How can I resolve it?

Comment: Have you you verified that the archive does have the directories as expected? What method do you use to unzip it? Show your code.

Comment: Yes it runs well on localhost and it has directory inside it, here's my code : $zip = new ZipArchive; if ($zip->open("module/$file[name]") === TRUE) { $zip->extractTo('module/'); }

Comment: @Alireza I updated my answer based on your code. Let me know.

Comment: If PHP's ZipArchive really doesn't support extraction preserving directory structure (which I'm not sure about), alternatively you can use the Linux `unzip` command which does preserve directories by default. E.g. ` exec( 'unzip -x -d ' . $destDir . ' -f ' . $pathToZip );`

Comment: @MarcellFülöp my code gives back the directory structure on localhost, the problem is on the host

Comment: Let me guess: the host you're talking about runs Linux and the local system runs Windows.

Comment: @JeroenvandenBroek : That's right

Comment: PHP is pretty well known for small issues like this where one OS behaves differently from others. This ranges from certain formats for `date()` not being available in Windows to `setlocale()` not being thread safe in Windows (not sure if that's fixed nowadays). Whenever problems like these arise, it's probably best to make sure that your code works on both platforms in case you ever want to switch providers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved! Here's what I did :
I change the code of creating zip file into this function from php.net user comments :

```
function addFolderToZip($dir, $zipArchive){
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            //Add the directory
            $zipArchive->addEmptyDir($dir);
            // Loop through all the files
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                //If it's a folder, run the function again!
                if(!is_file($dir . $file)){
                    // Skip parent and root directories
                    if(($file !== ".") && ($file !== "..")){
                        addFolderToZip($dir . $file . "/", $zipArchive);
                    }
                }else{
                    // Add the files
                    $zipArchive->addFile($dir . $file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open("$modName.zip", ZipArchive::CREATE);
addFolderToZip("$modName/", $zip);
$zip->close();
```

And in the host I wrote just this code to extract the zipped file :

```
copy($file["tmp_name"], "module/$file[name]");
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open("module/$file[name]") === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('module/');
}
$zip->close();
```

It created the folder and sub-folders. The only bug left is that it extracts every file in all subfolders in the main folder too, so there is two versions of each file in subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not actually provide a function that extracts a ZIP including its directory structure. I found the following code in a user comment in the manual:

```
function unzip($zipfile)
{
    $zip = zip_open($zipfile);
    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))    {
        zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry);
        if (substr(zip_entry_name($zip_entry), -1) == '/') {
            $zdir = substr(zip_entry_name($zip_entry), 0, -1);
            if (file_exists($zdir)) {
                trigger_error('Directory "<b>' . $zdir . '</b>" exists', E_USER_ERROR);
                return false;
            }
            mkdir($zdir);
        }
        else {
            $name = zip_entry_name($zip_entry);
            if (file_exists($name)) {
                trigger_error('File "<b>' . $name . '</b>" exists', E_USER_ERROR);
                return false;
            }
            $fopen = fopen($name, "w");
            fwrite($fopen, zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry)), zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
        }
        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }
    zip_close($zip);
    return true;
}
```

Source [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php#79057).

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't look developer-friendly! I use the same code on localhost and it gives back the directory structure

Comment: Developer friendly or not, as far as I can find it's your only option besides using a third party class or script. Which is essentially the same thing. As for this working locally: difference between Linux and Windows I guess.

Answer (score 0):

try [DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php)

**instead of using:**

> $path = $someDirectory.'/'.$someFile;

**use:**

> $path = $someDirectory. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$someFile;

Change your code to this:

> $zip = new ZipArchive;
>   if ($zip->open("module. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$file[name]") === TRUE) {
>   $zip->extractTo('module. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR');
>   }

And it will work for both operating systems.

Good luck,

Comment: Thanks, I tested it on host but still have the same problem